# Unable to serialize property [OpenApi maven codgen plugin]

Tags: java, json, serialization, nullable, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

i'm using "openapi-generator-maven-plugin" version 6.2.1 for generate modules from a YAML file and consume a RestAPI.

The code that is generated from the plugin looks fine and it work great with "GET" requests, the problem that i've encountered so far, is on "POST" requests. Apparently when I pass an object with null values (even if they are nullable) it throws "Unable to serialize property" from [org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Marshaller], even if the object is Serializable.

More specific:

I've this object generated from the plugin.

```
/*
 * MS00140
 * No description provided (generated by Openapi Generator https://github.com/openapitools/openapi-generator)
 *
 * The version of the OpenAPI document: 1.0
 * 
 *
 * NOTE: This class is auto generated by OpenAPI Generator (https://openapi-generator.tech).
 * https://openapi-generator.tech
 * Do not edit the class manually.
 */


package org.openapitools.client.model;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Arrays;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import org.openapitools.jackson.nullable.JsonNullable;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import org.openapitools.jackson.nullable.JsonNullable;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;

/**
 * ModelFile
 */
@JsonPropertyOrder({
  ModelFile.JSON_PROPERTY_LINK,
  ModelFile.JSON_PROPERTY_NAME,
  ModelFile.JSON_PROPERTY_MIME_TYPE,
  ModelFile.JSON_PROPERTY_DATA
})
@JsonTypeName("File")
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.JavaClientCodegen", date = "2022-11-21T13:50:57.834020300+01:00[Europe/Berlin]")
public class ModelFile implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_LINK = "link";
  private JsonNullable<String> link = JsonNullable.<String>undefined();

  public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_NAME = "name";
  private JsonNullable<String> name = JsonNullable.<String>undefined();

  public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_MIME_TYPE = "mimeType";
  private JsonNullable<String> mimeType = JsonNullable.<String>undefined();

  public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_DATA = "data";
  private JsonNullable<byte[]> data = JsonNullable.<byte[]>undefined();

  public ModelFile() {
  }

  public ModelFile link(String link) {
    this.link = JsonNullable.<String>of(link);
    
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * Get link
   * @return link
  **/
  @javax.annotation.Nullable
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")
  @JsonIgnore

  public String getLink() {
        return link.orElse(null);
  }

  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_LINK)
  @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)

  public JsonNullable<String> getLink_JsonNullable() {
    return link;
  }
  
  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_LINK)
  public void setLink_JsonNullable(JsonNullable<String> link) {
    this.link = link;
  }

  public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = JsonNullable.<String>of(link);
  }


  public ModelFile name(String name) {
    this.name = JsonNullable.<String>of(name);
    
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * Get name
   * @return name
  **/
  @javax.annotation.Nullable
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")
  @JsonIgnore

  public String getName() {
        return name.orElse(null);
  }

  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_NAME)
  @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)

  public JsonNullable<String> getName_JsonNullable() {
    return name;
  }
  
  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_NAME)
  public void setName_JsonNullable(JsonNullable<String> name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = JsonNullable.<String>of(name);
  }


  public ModelFile mimeType(String mimeType) {
    this.mimeType = JsonNullable.<String>of(mimeType);
    
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * Get mimeType
   * @return mimeType
  **/
  @javax.annotation.Nullable
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")
  @JsonIgnore

  public String getMimeType() {
        return mimeType.orElse(null);
  }

  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_MIME_TYPE)
  @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)

  public JsonNullable<String> getMimeType_JsonNullable() {
    return mimeType;
  }
  
  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_MIME_TYPE)
  public void setMimeType_JsonNullable(JsonNullable<String> mimeType) {
    this.mimeType = mimeType;
  }

  public void setMimeType(String mimeType) {
    this.mimeType = JsonNullable.<String>of(mimeType);
  }


  public ModelFile data(byte[] data) {
    this.data = JsonNullable.<byte[]>of(data);
    
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * Get data
   * @return data
  **/
  @javax.annotation.Nullable
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")
  @JsonIgnore

  public byte[] getData() {
        return data.orElse(null);
  }

  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_DATA)
  @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)

  public JsonNullable<byte[]> getData_JsonNullable() {
    return data;
  }
  
  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_DATA)
  public void setData_JsonNullable(JsonNullable<byte[]> data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public void setData(byte[] data) {
    this.data = JsonNullable.<byte[]>of(data);
  }


  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    ModelFile _file = (ModelFile) o;
    return equalsNullable(this.link, _file.link) &&
        equalsNullable(this.name, _file.name) &&
        equalsNullable(this.mimeType, _file.mimeType) &&
        equalsNullable(this.data, _file.data);
  }

  private static <T> boolean equalsNullable(JsonNullable<T> a, JsonNullable<T> b) {
    return a == b || (a != null && b != null && a.isPresent() && b.isPresent() && Objects.deepEquals(a.get(), b.get()));
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(hashCodeNullable(link), hashCodeNullable(name), hashCodeNullable(mimeType), hashCodeNullable(data));
  }

  private static <T> int hashCodeNullable(JsonNullable<T> a) {
    if (a == null) {
      return 1;
    }
    return a.isPresent() ? Arrays.deepHashCode(new Object[]{a.get()}) : 31;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("class ModelFile {\n");
    sb.append("    link: ").append(toIndentedString(link)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    name: ").append(toIndentedString(name)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    mimeType: ").append(toIndentedString(mimeType)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    data: ").append(toIndentedString(data)).append("\n");
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
  }

  /**
   * Convert the given object to string with each line indented by 4 spaces
   * (except the first line).
   */
  private String toIndentedString(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
      return "null";
    }
    return o.toString().replace("\n", "\n    ");
  }

}
```

When I make the request the only property that I set for the moment is the "link" property, because the REST service knows what to do.

```
public File getFileByLink(String link) throws WebServiceException, DataNotFoundException {
        
        log.debug("Executing---> getFileByLink()");
        
        File file;
            
        try {
            
            ModelFile inputFile = new ModelFile();
            
            inputFile.setLink(link);
            
            file = utilityApi.apiUtilityGetFileByLinkPost(inputFile);
            
            if (file == null) {
                throw new DataNotFoundException("Error!");
            }
            
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            throw new WebServiceException(e.getCode() + " - " + e.getMessage());            
        } catch (DataNotFoundException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new WebServiceException(e);
        }
        
        log.debug("Leaving ---> getFileByLink()");
        
        return file;        
    }
```

Now when it perform the actual request and try to serialize the object throws this error:

```
    13:55:36,124 SEVERE [org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Marshaller] (default task-1) Unable to serialize property 'data_JsonNullable' from org.openapitools.client.model.ModelFile
    13:55:36,133 SEVERE [org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Marshaller] (default task-1) Generating incomplete JSON
    13:55:36,145 ERROR [it.inps.itg.web.exception.WebServiceException] (default task-1) WebServiceException in Class: TemplateAction.java and Method: executeAction Message: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY008205: JSON Binding serialization error javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Unable to serialize property 'data_JsonNullable' from org.openapitools.client.model.ModelFile Cause: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY008205: JSON Binding serialization error javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Unable to serialize property 'data_JsonNullable' from org.openapitools.client.model.ModelFile
```

At first I didn't use the property `<serializableModel>true</serializableModel>`, and I thought that the object could not be searialized for this problem, but even if the class implement the Serializable interface the problem still occur.

If can help, I've tried to set values to all the object's properties and as long as they are not null, there's non serialization problems. The problem occur when there's at least one property that is null.